# GPAC "cannot create config file"

Tags: configure

I'm trying to play a file using GPAC using the command `MP4Client /path/to/file.mkv` and I get these errors:

```
GPAC config file .gpacrc not found in /home/sth - creating new file
[Core] default modules not found
Cannot create config file .gpacrc in /home/sth directory
Error: Configuration File not found
```

I tried running it with sudo but still no luck. Anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did have the same problem in the past and it was caused by installing GPAC with:

```
sudo apt-get install gpac
```

I fixed it then by installing GPAC debian package from [GPAC Nightly Builds](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/) site.

Comment: yep it works now! thx XD